# $.post without user click.

Tags: javascript, php, post, call

On my website I was loading information when the user clicked on a button with the following call (example):

```
<button onClick="Click();"></button> 

function Click(){
   $.post("MyPhpCode.php",{a: User, b: Info }, function(result){
         //Do shomething
   }
}
```

But now I need this information to be loaded when the page opens, without the need to make any clicks. How can I do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`$( document ).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    $.post("MyPhpCode.php",{a: User, b: Info }, function(result){
      // Do shomething
    }
});
```

Note: Code included inside `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready. So use the one matches your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("MyPhpCode.php",{a: User, b: Info }, function(result){
         //Do shomething
    }
});
```